# XPath2Tester throws the markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed in Jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter

XPath2Tester throws

```
"Exception:net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
"

*/[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login"  and enabled="true"]
```

Not sure what went wrong.

[image]

[image]

When I tried same with XPathTester throws

```
Exception:javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
```

[image]

When i tried all the below works in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output it returns the results.

```
//*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login"]
//*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login"] [@enabled="true"]
//*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login" and @enabled="true"]
```

But when i tried same in Jmeter using XPath Extractor doesn't works

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something very weird, to wit you try to apply an [XPath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to the response of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which returns **server response** while in your image you show us JMeter .jmx test plan.

You will not have anything from JMeter test plan in the server response therefore your approach is vague, try reconsidering what you're doing.

If for any reason you need to get some value from the .jmx test plan - you should configure your HTTP Request sampler as follows (see [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article)

- protocol: `file`
- path: `C:/JMETER/PROJECT_ST_FINIEX/SmartTime_Fenix_TimeCardLoad_SteppingThreadGroup.jmx`

[image]

This way your XPath query will be successful, however I fail to see the reason for having this form of information as a JMeter Variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're using XPath2 Test on HTML document.

XPath2 Tester and [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) as implemented in JMeter 5.0 only works with XML, if you want to use XPath on HTML (which is not advised) then you can alternatively use XPath Tester and [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as they allow to tidy document to make it XML well formed.

To extract data from HTML, use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

Comment: I tried the XPath Extractor  too, but no luck. But when i tried all //*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login"]
//*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login"] [@enabled="true"]
//*[@testname="TimeCardLoad_Login" and @enabled="true"]    in  All the below works in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output     it gave me the results but not working same in the Jmeter